# Show that H is a normal subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a multiplicative group and let $H \subseteq G $ be a subgroup. Suppose that for any $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ in $G$ satisfying $a_1H = a_2H$ and $b_1H = b_2H$, we have $a_1b_1H = a_2b_2H$. Show that H is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: If I have any idea, I would have put them here.

Comment: What is your definition of normal subgroup?

Comment: for all g in G and h in H, ghg^-1 belongs to H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if it is the kernel of some homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow K$, for some group $K$. (If you've not seen this before, then I recommend trying to prove it using the first isomorphism theorem).

Your condition allows you to write down a *quotient group* $G/H$. If you've not seen this before, this is the group
$$G/H = \{aH: a \in G\}$$ 
of cosets of $H$ in $G$. The group operation is defined by $aH\cdot bH = abH$, and your condition says that this is well-defined. Can you complete the proof that $G/H$ does form a group with this operation?

Once you have such a group, there's a canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G/H$ with kernel $H$. Can you give this homomorphism? This then completes the proof.

Comment: Is it possible to not use group action to solve this question because I have not learnt it yet?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write group operation, not group action!

Comment: i am not sure if this is correct: to show G/H is a group:
1) HH = H so identity of G/H exists
2) if x belongs to G/H, then x = aH and x^-1 = a^-1H and this is also in G/H as x^-1 is in G
3) (aHbH)cH = abcH = aH(bHcH) using the operation defined
4)if aH and bH in G/H then aHbH = abH also in G/H as ab in G

Comment: i am not sure how to show the canonical homomorphism though

Comment: is it just f(a) = aK?

Comment: If you meant to write f(a) = aH, then yes, it is!

Comment: why $ab^{-1} \in H$ iff $a^{-1}b \in H$? and why accordingly I get the result?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that on a bus in a rush and it was sloppy, so I deleted it. A correct proof that the inverse is well-defined is: If $aH = bH$, then there exists some $h_1, h_2 \in H$ such that $ah_1 = bh_2$. Then $b^{-1}a = h_2h_1^{-1} \in H$. So $b^{-1}aH = H$, and as trivially $a^{-1}H = a^{-1}H$, using the multiplication property given in the question we have $b^{-1}H = b^{-1}aa^{-1}H = a^{-1}H.$